# Cannot create a VM in the Brazil South region

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I'm looking to create a new VM in the South Brazil region in Microsoft Azure. However, the region is now showing up in the list of available regions when I go and create a VM. Do I need a billing address in Brazil for this? The [Azure Regions](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services) page only mentions that I need to have one for deployments in Australia and New Zealand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We contacted Azure billing support and they enabled the Brazil South region for us. According to the support representative:

> Once the subscription is deployed, users get access to regions on availability basis, If you need any specific region it is usually on request basis.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a billing address in Brazil to use VMs in the Brazil South Azure region.

Take into account that not all sizes/series are available in all regions.

At this moment only these sizes are available in Brazil South:

- Basic tier: all sizes (A0 to A4).
- Standard tier: sizes A0 to A7.

D-Series and G-Series VMs are not available in the Brazil South region yet.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to create a Basic A1 VM but the Brazil South region is just not showing up in the list of regions for me. Could it be sold out or something?

Comment: I've just tried creating a Basic A1 VM in both the existing and preview portals, and have Brazil South available in the region/affinity group list.

Comment: I tried the preview portal and there is no Brazil South either. Here is what I have: South Central US, West US, East US, East US 2, Central US, North Europe, West Europe, Southeast Asia, East Asia, Japan West, Japan East. This is a BizSpark subscription, can this be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried going through the "From gallery" creation, there you can select the region in the fourth step, maybe you get to have Brazil South this way.

Comment: Also, you can try creating your VM through PowerShell, here's a basic guide: http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/windows-azure-virtual-machines-with-powershell-basics/

Comment: Tried the Gallery approach, still no luck. That could be an account issue, here is a similar thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/02c33f7a-f28a-4e36-bd5d-2e3575ec19b5/cannot-create-azure-storage-on-brazil-south?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76392/discussion-between-jamix-and-gbellmann).